# PhantomJs set header margin to 0 when rendering pdf

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, pdf, phantomjs

I'm using Node.js and the module phridge (version 1.0.3) to render a pdf with PhantomJs.

I want to render a pdf without any margins in the header and footer. For the moment I only found a hack to remove the left and right margin, by means of a negative left and right margin.

An example for printing a header and footer with pagenumbers can be found here:
https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/printheaderfooter.js

```
// creates a new webpage internally
var page = phantom.createPage(),
    outputFile = path.join(options.destDir, options.destFile);

/*global window:false */
// page.run(fn) runs fn inside PhantomJS
page.run(html, outputFile, options.header, options.footer, options.delay,
  function (html, outputFile, header, footer, delay, resolve /*, reject*/) {
  // Here we're inside PhantomJS, so we can't reference variables in the scope.
  // 'this' is an instance of PhantomJS' WebPage as returned by require("webpage").create()
  var page = this;

  page.content = html;
  page.viewportSize = { width: 1190, height: 1684 }; // 144dpi

  page.paperSize = {
    format: 'A4',
    header: {
      // How do I set the margin to 0px? margin: 0px or border: 0px doesn't work.
      height: '80px'
      contents: phantom.callback(function (pageNum, numPages) {
        return header.contents.replace(/<%= pageNum %>/g, pageNum).replace(/<%= numPages %>/g, numPages);
      })
    },
    footer: {
      height: '80px'
      contents: phantom.callback(function (pageNum, numPages) {
        return footer.contents.replace(/<%= pageNum %>/g, pageNum).replace(/<%= numPages %>/g, numPages);
      })
    },
  };

  // Wait until JavaScript has run
  window.setTimeout(function () {
    page.render(outputFile, { format: 'pdf', quality: '100' });
    page.close();
    page = null;
    resolve(outputFile);
  }, delay);
```

I removed the left and right header margins by using a negative margin. For this I used inline style.
For example when **header.contents** is:

```
<div style="background-color: rgb(230, 231, 232);margin:-20px;height:80px;">
  <img style="text-align:center" src="file:///C:/image.png" alt="image">
</div>
```

In an earlier attempt to remove the margins I included following internal CSS stylesheet. Unfortunately, it seems like this style is not applied. Elsewhere I read that the cause for this behavior is the fact that only inline style is applied when using the phantom.callback().

```
<style type="text/css">
  @page {
    margin: 0;
  }
  * {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }
  body {
    margin: 0px;
  }
</style>
```

How should I remove the top and bottom margin of the header and footer?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following CSS for the html files you're rendering to pdf:

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Seems like otherwise`body` has some padding at top and bottom "by default".

Comment: This doesn't help to me. It seems that the header top margin even grows with the header height. See here https://playground.jsreport.net/#playground/v3rraMiDC/3

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the header and footer is rendered differently on different platforms (Linux, Windows) because the dpi is different.

Here is a discussion about it: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phantomjs/YQIyxLWhmr0

Changing the **zoomFactor** based on the platform removed the white gaps:

```
page.zoomFactor = (PLATFORM === 'linux'?  0.654545: 0.9)
```